# How to use a drawable with adjustable text as notification action icon

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-drawable

**What I need**

What I want to achieve is something like

[image: this]

where it should be possible to programmatically set the number displayed within the icon.
I.e. I want a notification action icon with a programmatically adjustable text.

Is there a simple way to achieve this? It does not seem to be possible to add a TextView to an android drawable and set the text when I'm building my notification. What other ways are there?

**Code**

The rough code for building my notification is (although I think it's not necessary for answering the question):

```java
private void buildNotification() {
    createNotificationChannel();

    Intent playbackActionIntent = new Intent(this, MediaPlayerService.class);
    playbackActionIntent.setAction(ACTION_BACKWARD);
    PendingIntent backwardAction = PendingIntent.getService(this, 3, playbackActionIntent, 0);

    String audioTitle = "testTitle";
    String albumTitle = "testAlbumTitle";

    // Create a new Notification
    mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            // Hide the timestamp
            .setShowWhen(false)
            // Set the Notification style
            .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    // Attach our MediaSession token
                    .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())
                    // Show our playback controls in the compat view
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2))
            // Set the Notification color
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_new)
            // Set Notification content information
            .setContentText(albumTitle)
            .setContentTitle(audioTitle)
            // Set the visibility for the lock screen
            .setVisibility(VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            // Add playback actions
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_media_backward, "backward", backwardAction)

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

So for `R.drawable.ic_media_backward` I want a drawable with an adjustable text as in the linked image.

Any help is appreciated! So far I could not find anything that would solve my problem.

Comment: You would have to use a custom RemoteViews for the Notification. Interestingly, your picture looks different than the "normal" notification which I get when I use your code (on a Pixel XL emulator running Api Level 27). So maybe you're already halfway there?

Comment: Ah, no, the image is from the Audible app notification and was just to demonstrate what I want to achieve. I'm no where near it ;( Thanks for the comment though, I'll have a look into RemoteViews.